# OpenGL glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) work only first time

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I try relate Qml and OpenGL, so I take example openglunderqml
as in example I create own class

```
class QProject1Main : public QQuickItem

void QProject1Main::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win) {
    if (win) {
        connect(win, SIGNAL(beforeRendering()), this, SLOT(paint()), Qt::DirectConnection);
        win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    }
}

void QProject1Main::paint() {
    qDebug() << "QProject1Main::paint()";
    qreal ratio = window()->devicePixelRatio();
    int w = int(ratio * window()->width());
    int h = int(ratio * window()->height());
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

   // each iteration bg color change from green to read
    glClearColor(((float)++idx)/100, 0.3, 0.3, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
   // triangle visible only at first iteration
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
      glVertex3f( 0.1f, 0.8f, 0.1f);
      glVertex3f(-0.8f,-0.8f, 0.1f);
      glVertex3f( 0.8f,-0.8f, 0.1f);
    glEnd();
}
```

I'm resize window to call paint method and see that background color changed but triangle paint only first time (

Comment: Not so much an answer to your question, but a comment from someone who  is learning OpenGL themselves: you may want to look into the modern, retained-style of doing things in OpenGL. As you're a newbie, going through a couple of immediate mode tutorials won't kill you, but I'd suggest starting off your OpenGL adventure strong. [Here is one of the more oft-recommended modern OpenGL tutorials on the web.](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)

Comment: thank you, I'll read this tutorial, but better start study OpenGL with Qt

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you need to call wglSwapBuffers after glEnd. Maybe problem is not in glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES), maybe you have wrong blending mode or use texture color without texture.

Comment: looks fine, but I do not know where I can get (HDC hdc) for swapBuffer (

Comment: @Gilbarad using modern OpenGL does not preclude working with Qt. If you are just learning, there really isn't any reason to start with a long obsolete version...

Comment: @Unick `wglXXX` functions only apply to windows. A quick search on Google however reveals that QGLWidget has a swapBuffers() function.

Comment: @fintelia Qt use Open GL 4, and I am not using QGLWidget I am using Qml

Comment: Did you use OpenGL in another place of program? Also do you have correct value in ratio, w, h?

Comment: @Unick, no, I take code from Qt example and put triangle code instead of shaders. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html